# How to Change a Value in a HashMap from a Different Class

Tags: java, hashmap

I have written about 1680 lines of code, mainly creating a GUI. I am finally trying to get the GUI to "do something interesting." However, the code I have is not producing the desired result. I have a few relevant pieces of code below.

First I have a class CharLocStorage to create the hashmap and give the hashmap some starting values.

```
public static class CharLocStorage 
{
    private HashMap<String, Integer> charLocStorage = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
    public HashMap<String, Integer> getCharLocStorageMap() 
    {
        boolean bContainsKey = charLocStorage.containsKey("Han Solo");
        if (bContainsKey == false)
        {
            charLocStorage.put("Han Solo",4);
        }
        boolean bContainsKey2 = charLocStorage.containsKey("Luke Skywalker");
        if (bContainsKey2 == false)
        {
            charLocStorage.put("Luke Skywalker",4);
        }
        return charLocStorage;
    }
}
```

Second I have a class CreatePlanetFrame to create a JFrame for a planet. (There is a second hashmap here but I will never need to change the values in this hashmap. This second hashmap works fine and has nothing to do with the question.)

```
public static class CreatePlanetFrame
{
    CharLocStorage a = new CharLocStorage();
    public void createPlanetFrame (String sPlanetName)
    {
```

....

```
String sLocName = sPlanetName;

                    HashMap<String,Integer> hmap = new HashMap<String,Integer>();

                    /*Adding elements to HashMap*/
                    hmap.put("Bastion",1);
                    hmap.put("Bescane",2);
                    hmap.put("Borosk",3);
                    hmap.put("Dantooine",4);
                    hmap.put("Dubrillion",5);
                    hmap.put("Entralla",6);
                    hmap.put("Garqi",7);
                    hmap.put("Gree",8);
                    hmap.put("Jaemus",9);
                    hmap.put("Kalee",10);
                    hmap.put("Moltok",11);
                    hmap.put("Muunilinst",12);
                    hmap.put("Mygeeto",13);
                    hmap.put("Ord Biniir",14);
                    hmap.put("Ord Trasi",15);
                    hmap.put("Valc",16);
                    hmap.put("Yaga Minor",17);

                int nlocPlanet = hmap.get(sLocName);

                    HashMap<String, Integer> charLocStorage = a.getCharLocStorageMap();

                    /*Adding elements to HashMap*/


                int a;
                String sPersonnel = "";
                for (a=1;a<=2;a++)
                {
                    if (a==1) {sPersonnel = "Han Solo";}
                    if (a==2) {sPersonnel = "Luke Skywalker";}
                    int nlocPersonnel = charLocStorage.get(sPersonnel);
                    if (nlocPersonnel == nlocPlanet)
                    {
                        JPanel panelDA1 = new JPanel();

                        JLabel labelDA1 = new JLabel(sPersonnel);

                        JPanel panelDAA1 = new JPanel();
                        panelDAA1.add(labelDA1);
                        panelDA1.add(panelDAA1);

                        JButton buttonDA1 = new JButton("Move");
                        panelDA1.add(buttonDA1);
                        buttonDA1.addActionListener(new ActionMove());
                        buttonDA1.setName(sPersonnel);
```

....

Third, I have the class ActionMove.

```
public static class ActionMove implements ActionListener
{
    public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e) 
    {
        String sCharName = ((JButton)e.getSource()).getName();
        CreateMoveFrame CMF = new CreateMoveFrame();
        CMF.createMoveFrame(sCharName);
    }
}
```

Fourth and finally I have the class CreateMoveFrame.

```
    public static class CreateMoveFrame
{
    CharLocStorage a = new CharLocStorage();
    public void createMoveFrame (String sCharName)
    {
```

....

```
JPanel panel1 = new JPanel(new GridLayout(3,1));

        JLabel label1 = new JLabel("Move "+sCharName+" to ");

        JPanel panel2 = new JPanel();
        panel2.add(label1);
        panel1.add(panel2);

        String[] choices = { "Bastion","Bescane", "Borosk","Dantooine","Dubrillion","Entralla","Garqi","Gree", "Jaemus","Kalee","Moltok","Muunilinst","Mygeeto","Ord Biniir", "Ord Trasi","Valc","Yaga Minor"};

        final JComboBox<String> cb = new JComboBox<String>(choices);

        cb.setVisible(true);
        panel1.add(cb);

        JPanel panel3 = new JPanel();

            JButton button1 = new JButton("MOVE");
            panel3.add(button1);
            //button1.addActionListener(new ActionMoveClick());
            button1.setName(sCharName);

                HashMap<String,Integer> hmap = new HashMap<String,Integer>();

                /*Adding elements to HashMap*/
                hmap.put("Bastion",1);
                hmap.put("Bescane",2);
                hmap.put("Borosk",3);
                hmap.put("Dantooine",4);
                hmap.put("Dubrillion",5);
                hmap.put("Entralla",6);
                hmap.put("Garqi",7);
                hmap.put("Gree",8);
                hmap.put("Jaemus",9);
                hmap.put("Kalee",10);
                hmap.put("Moltok",11);
                hmap.put("Muunilinst",12);
                hmap.put("Mygeeto",13);
                hmap.put("Ord Biniir",14);
                hmap.put("Ord Trasi",15);
                hmap.put("Valc",16);
                hmap.put("Yaga Minor",17);

                String sLocName = cb.getSelectedItem().toString();
                int nLocPlanet = hmap.get(sLocName);

            button1.addActionListener
            (new ActionListener() 
                {
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
                    {
                        a.charLocStorage.put(sCharName,nLocPlanet);
                        HashMap<String,Integer> charLocStorage = a.getCharLocStorageMap();
                        charLocStorage.put(sCharName,nLocPlanet);
                        frame9.dispose();
                    }          
                }
            );
```

....

Everything appears to work except that the value "nLocPlanet" is not being updated in the hashmap. (Han Solo and Luke Skywalker both appear on Dantooine but I can't get them to move elsewhere, and I can print out both sCharName and nLocPlanet using the second move button.)

I apologize for the length of the post, I wanted to make sure that all the relevant code was visible.

(I am writing the code in BlueJ. I do not have any syntax errors.)

Comment: Please update your question to contain *only the necessary information*. There is just way too much information and no clarity.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the issue. I forgot to refer to the class of the original hashmap in the button1 Action Listener. In addition, the hashmap has to be a static variable.

```
button1.addActionListener
            (new ActionListener() 
                {
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
                    {
                        HashMap<String,Integer> charLocStorage = a.getCharLocStorageMap();
                        CharLocStorage.charLocStorage.put(sCharName,nLocPlanet);
                        frame9.dispose();
                    }          
                }
            );
```

and

```
public static class CharLocStorage 
{
    private static HashMap<String, Integer> charLocStorage = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
    public HashMap<String, Integer> getCharLocStorageMap() 
    {
        boolean bContainsKey = charLocStorage.containsKey("Han Solo");
        if (bContainsKey == false)
        {
            charLocStorage.put("Han Solo",4);
        }
        boolean bContainsKey2 = charLocStorage.containsKey("Luke Skywalker");
        if (bContainsKey2 == false)
        {
            charLocStorage.put("Luke Skywalker",4);
        }
        return charLocStorage;
    }
}
```